# Сгруппировать выборку по дате PIVOT + GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

изначально есть такая таблица со значениями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно строки со столбцом title сделать столбцами выбрать из 4 колонок thick минимальное значение и всю эту выборку вывести по дате, получился такой запрос:

```
SELECT [DateSurv] AS ДатаПроведения, TypeID AS ТипОбсл, [1П], [6Д], [6П], [10Д], [10П], [11П], [11Д], [12П], [12Д], [15Д], [20П], [26Д], [26П], [28Д], [28/2П], [28П] FROM
(SELECT Point.Orders, Point.PointID, Point.Title, SurvMain.DateSurv, SurvMain.TypeID, MinThick = ( SELECT MIN(i) FROM ( VALUES (PointUZT.Thick),(PointUZT.Thick2),(PointUZT.Thick3),(PointUZT.Thick4)) t(i)) FROM Storage.Cluster INNER JOIN
                         Storage.Field ON Storage.Cluster.FieldID = Storage.Field.FieldID INNER JOIN
                         Tech.Well ON Storage.Cluster.ClusterID = Tech.Well.ClusterID INNER JOIN
                         Tech.Point ON Tech.Well.WellID = Tech.Point.WellID INNER JOIN
                         Survey.PointUZT ON Tech.Point.PointID = Survey.PointUZT.PointID INNER JOIN
                         Survey.Main AS SurvMain ON Survey.PointUZT.SurvID = SurvMain.SurvID JOIN
                         Storage.Main ON Storage.Field.MainID = Storage.Main.MainID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Storage.Module ON Storage.Field.ModuleID = Storage.Module.ModuleID where Tech.Well.WellID = 1 AND Tech.Point.StatusID = 1) p
PIVOT  
(  
Min(MinThick) 
FOR Title IN  
( [1П],[6Д],[6П],[10Д],[10П],[11П],[11Д],[12П],[12Д],[15Д],[20П], [26Д], [26П], [28Д],[28/2П], [28П])  
) AS pvt
```

Получается такой вывод, что каждая величина отдельно по дате выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает это происходит из за типа обследования. заранее сгруппируйте записи до даты, типа и title, оберните это внешним запросом и в нем делайте pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С внутреннего Select-a убрал 2 поля Point.Orders, Point.PointID и стало выводить, то, что нужно даже без группировки

Comment: PIVOT - это и есть GROUP BY + "синтаксический сахар"

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение!